# Input field value should not be greater than other field value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input fields one for advance payment and other for full payment, which are fetched from the database in array.

If `onchange` or `keyup` the advance payment is greater than full payment, Then the advance payment should not be entered or should be equal to full payment.

I am trying with this code

```html
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $full_payemnt; ?>" id="full_payment_<?php echo $i; ?>">
<input type="text" id="advance_payment_<?php echo $i; ?>" class="advance">
```

```js
$('.advance').on('change keyup blur', function(e){ 
  var fullPay = $('#full_payment_'+id[1]).val();
  var advancePay = $('#advance_payment_'+id[1]).val();
  console.log( parseInt(advancePay) > parseInt(fullPay))
    if (parseInt(advancePay ) > parseInt(fullPay)) {
       e.preventDefault();     
       $('#advance_payment_'+id[1]).val(fullPay);
    }
});
```

Comment: How is this related to regex? Is that tag correct?

Comment: Where  `id[1]` is coming from ?

Comment: @JuniorJoanis - these input fields are in multiple rows thats why i assigned id [1].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, I think you want this.

```js
$('.advance').on('change keyup blur', function(e){ 
  id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
 id = id_arr.split("_");
  var fullPay = $('#fullPayment_'+id[1]).val();
  var advancePay = $('#advancePayment_'+id[1]).val();
    if ($(this).val() > parseInt(fullPay)) {
       e.preventDefault();     
       $(this).val(fullPay);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <input type="text" value="12" id="fullPayment_1">
  <input type="text" id="advancePayment_1" class="advance">
</tr>
<br>
<tr>
  <input type="text" value="19" id="fullPayment_2">
  <input type="text" id="advancePayment_2" class="advance">
</tr>
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example of how you can do it.

```js
var $full = $('[name=full]');
var $adv = $('[name=adv]');

$adv.on('keyup keydown', function(e) {
  var fullPay = parseInt($full.val(), 10);
  var advPay = parseInt($adv.val(), 10); //tell the parser it is base 10

  if (advPay > fullPay &&
    e.keyCode !== 46 // keycode for delete
    &&
    e.keyCode !== 8 // keycode for backspace
  ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $adv.val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="full" />
<input type="number" name="adv" />
```

Comment: if input name is like `name="data[<?php echo $i; ?>][adv]"` then can it work with it.

Comment: You don't have to use the `[name=<name>]` selector, this was an example. You can use `#id` as well. Any selector should work. If you want to use the name and you have brackets then use quote around the name `[name="data[somename]"]`

Comment: can you give working jsfiddle example. that how it works with multiple rows of table.

Answer (score 2):

Made some changes to [`Sam Battat`'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50647138/6349060) so that each time a wrong entry is being typed it erase the entered number instead of clearing the field.

```js
var $full = $('[name=full]');
var $adv = $('[name=adv]');

$adv.on('keyup keydown', function(e) {
  var fullPay = parseInt($full.val(), 10);
  var advPay = parseInt($adv.val(), 10); //tell the parser it is base 10

  if (advPay > fullPay &&
    e.keyCode !== 46 // keycode for delete
    &&
    e.keyCode !== 8 // keycode for backspace
  ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $the_value = $adv.val();
    $the_value = $the_value.substring(0, $the_value.length - 1);
    $adv.val($the_value);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="full" />
<input type="number" name="adv" />
```

Comment: i am trying it like this on  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/movbkj1x/2/) . but it is not working for me.

Comment: because `id_arr = $(this).attr('id');` is not gonna give you anything.

Comment: @SamBattat - i want to work it on multiple rows then how can i manage it.